# Do Gaudiyas consider Allah and Jehovah also as "Supreme Personality of Godhead"?

Tags: other-religions, gaudiya-vaishnavism

From [this article](http://www.purebhakti.com/teachers/bhakti-discourses/21-discourses-2002/1069-the-proof-of-reality).

> We accept Sri Krsna as the Supreme Personality of Godhead, but the father of Jesus Christ, God, Allah, Khoda, and Jehovah are also said to be the Supreme Personality of Godhead. There are not two Gods. The fact is that the Supreme Lord is one without a second. In different languages, in different countries, and in different sections of the world, people call that same Supreme Lord by various names.

Steven Rosen includes Vishnu and Rama as other equivalent names.

Is this the mainstream Gaudiya view?

Comment: No, it's only ISKCON.

Comment: Its simple every word, sentence and letter are epithet  name of God if you say Allah means  neti neti atma one which cannot be explained by any other its the starting letter of AUM

Answer (score 2):

Gaudiya Vaishnavas have many subsects.

1. The first is the lineage starting from Mahaprabhu.His conversations with Chand Kaji reveals that He never told that Allah is different from Sri Krishna. He was not that familiar with Christanity, probably met a group in South India though. Sri Chaitanya mentioned that "Adwaya jnana tattwa vastu krishner swarup" meaning Sri Krishna is Addvaya in Swarupa.
2. The lineage of His direct disciples lived in the muslim era and saw many temples demolished by the then islamic rulers.Even then neither did they  say anything against Islam nor did they say Krishna is Superior to Alla.
   (Ref: Sri Chaitanyadev, Swami Saradeshananda, Udbodhan).
3. The lineage starting with Srila Charandas Babaji, who was the pioneer in preaching Mahuprabhu's message in bengal did have many muslim devotees but did not make any conversion. He respected all deities and all religions. (Ref: His biography by Abha Sarkar).
4. The lineage starting from Prabhu Jagadbandhu also had no disrespect for any religion. Dr.Mahanamvrata Brahmachari of His lineage defined ISLAM as I  Shall Love All Msnkind. (Reference: Mahanaamvrata Rachanavali)
5. The last group is preaching now in India and abroad.They do not say anything against Islam  or Christanity but brand all hindu gods and goddesses except Radha-Krishna as demi-gods. It surprises me that they dyo not criticise the conecpt of formless Allah but are against the concept of formless Brahma. I think their intention is not to hurt the sentiments of other religions as that may hamper their activities in other countries.